# Apache using all 16 GB Memory, how to limit its processes and memory usage?

Tags: apache, out-of-memory, ubuntu-14.04

We are on 16GB AWS instance and I am finding it to be really slow. When I ran

```
ps -aux | grep apache
```

I can see about 60+ apache processes.

[image]

When I ran

```
watch -n 1 "echo -n 'Apache Processes: ' && ps -C apache2 --no-headers | wc -l && free -m"
```

It is showing almost all memory being used by apache.

[image]

When I ran

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richardforth/apache2buddy/master/apache2buddy.pl | perl
```

to see how to optimize Apache, it suggested me to increase number of MaxRequestWorkers so I made it 550. I also changed MaxConnectionsPerChild from 0 (unlimited) to 10000.

Here is my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf file

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers              5
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers          10
        MaxRequestWorkers        550
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

Can you tell me how can we optimize apache memory usage so it don't bring down the whole site down ?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem with an instance in EC2 and here's what I did and would suggest:

1. If you are using prefork, make sure that the module is loaded by typing these two commands
   `apache2 -l` and `sudo apache2 -M`
   If you can see the prefork module loaded in the results of either of these two commands then up to the next step. Otherwise, make sure to load it first or else you would be changing the configurations for nothing.
2. Run this command to find the average memory each apache2 process is using `ps aux | grep 'apache2' | awk '{print $6/1024;}' | awk '{avg += ($1 - avg) / NR;} END {print avg " MB";}'` Call that value `x`
3. Restart your apache server by using `sudo service apache2 restart` and take a note of how much free memory you have. What I did was subtract an extra `200MB-500MB` cushion from that free memory to be used later. Call that value `y`
4. Divide the value of free memory `y` over the amount of memory used per process `x` and that would be the value of `MaxRequestWorkers = y/x`
5. As for the value of `MaxConnectionsPerChild` then you can tweak it till you get the right configuration. It you make it too big, then the process will keep using more and more memory before being killed. If you make it too small, then the processes will die too quickly and that will present an overhead on your system. I usually keep it somewhere between `4000` and `10000`.
6. Some of these steps have been taken from the accepted answer in the following link: [StackExchange: httpd memory usage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187112/httpd-memory-usage) where one solution also suggested disabling some of the modules if you don't need them.

I would suggest you do steps 1-5 first and see if that solves your problem!

Good luck!

Comment: For "apache2 -l", I am seeing only these modules - 

Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c

I don't see prefork, how to enable it ? I am surprised as it is not showing either of prefork and worker mod ?

Comment: For me, I didn't see it either but I saw it loaded using `sudo apache2 -M`. If you couldn't see it loaded then you can do it automatically using `sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork` or you can do it manually, which might be a long process by finding the **.conf** file first and then uncomment the line that loads the prefork module. Good luck!