# Kubernetes pod memory vs cgroup

Tags: kubernetes, out-of-memory, cgroups

I am running apache in Kubernetes pod and I am troubled by random OOM kills of the apache process and I am unsure of the cause.

The pod has 600M memory limit and it seems it can consume it quite easily even though PHP has 128 MB limit per run. When observing `dmesg -w` I can regularly see:

```
[4019392.626796] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 4178127 (apache2) score 1137 or sacrifice child
[4019392.636520] Killed process 4178127 (apache2) total-vm:143960kB, anon-rss:22856kB, file-rss:10472kB, shmem-rss:28228kB
```

1. How can I be sure, that this OOM kill is related to the machine or to the pod limits?
2. There are several apache pods and I am not sure how to recognize the pod to which this process belonged. Is there a way?
3. It would be great if these were accessible within the pods, so one could see killed threads which actually belonged to the pod (ideally in error output). Is it possible?

Comment: Could you share the output of `kubectl get pods`, `kubectl logs ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}` and also `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` of the apache pod?

Comment: There is nothing in these logs - this happens ONLY on the node level. The pod itself is not killed and there are absolutely NO errors within these logs.

Comment: @Vojtěch did you get any way to know the limit for `Memory cgroup` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Covering your questions in the same order:

1. `kubectl get events` in the namespace where you run a pod. You will see Kubernetes OOM events among others. If there's nothing - it will be the kernel itself.
2. There's a [project called `pid2pod`](https://github.com/heptiolabs/pid2pod), but it greps only what's still running. The other option will be to route dmesg to stdout (on container OS level) and implement [centralized log collection with Kubernetes metadata enrichment](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/d339305a27326a98681e654eb5f4f9bd6882f3aa/stable/fluent-bit/templates/config.yaml#L82). Then every log event will have pod id in the metadata.
3. Not sure what are you trying to solve here. Usually, one pod (and I assume one container) is one process. Once it killed by OOM, there's nothing else that can take an action on this inside the pod. It's the controller's (`Deployment`) responsibility to react to this event and recreate the pod.

   If you just want to watch for OOMs within the remaining pods you may implement smth like [kubewatch](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch). Unfortunately, I don't have a project that lets you subscribe within a pod directly, but this can be used as an example. Or in case of centralized logging, you can subscribe to a log stream inside a pod.

Comment: 1. `get events` returns just unrelated logs. It seems these are only node-level events. If this is kernel - why does this happen? Does it mean the node itself is running out of memory? I tried `describe nodes` and there is: `memory request:4728813952 (33%)  limit:7493386752 (53%)` so I guess this should not be happening as there is still enough memory?

Comment: It's most likely caused by the pod limits giving the node memory utilization. Are you looking for events in your namespace? Also, note that events live only for 1h. You also can prove it's kubernetes OOM by looking at `kubectl get po <restarted-pod-id> -oyaml`, in `status` field there will be:  `Reason:       OOMKilled`

Comment: `<restarted-pod-id>` note - the pod itself IS NOT restarted. It just kills the apache processes INSIDE of it. The strange is that the node is not on its limits and the `kubectl top pods` is similar.

Comment: I see. Are there multiple apache processes inside a pod? Usually, a container is a single process, and once it exists the pod should exit too

Comment: The apache forks to several processes - so it does not kill the main process. But why this is not logged within the pod logs or kube events?

Comment: I see. Kubernetes doesn't know about this OOM because the container did not restart (because it killed only 1 child process, not the entrypoint) And it's not related to a host resources, because it kills based on cgroup resources. Try setting a maximum fork resources https://stackoverflow.com/a/41308773/923620 so that the total of all workers is less than a pod limit.

Comment: @MaxLobur is there any way to know the limit for cgroup ?

Comment: I guess the limit for the cgroup is the same like for the pod. It is just unfortunate that it doesn't kill the whole pod.